# How to solve changing location for Controls due to expansion in xcode 4.5 for UIView?

Tags: xcode, uiview, xcode4.3, xcode4.5

I have upgraded my xcode to 4.5 every thing is fine until I have added to my previous solution (which I had already developed it using xcode 4.3) new `UIView` which has a `UIImageview` control I have noticed that `UIImage` control location in **xib**  differ than it's location when i run my app on `ios5` devices

Any Idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: Please uncheck the use Autolayout option in all the xibs.

Comment: It founds on file inspector tab under Interface Builder Document section :)

Comment: ok i have tried it but it's no working

Comment: Then try to change the size to 3.5 inch from 4 inch for view in attribute inspector under simulator matrix :)

Comment: Are you using iPhone5 full screen layout?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that i've understand your question correctly.
Try to hide device's statusbar.

You can do it in a current target settings or programmatically:

[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden...

Comment: no this is not my question I notice that im my UIView I have UIImageview control I have notice that its location in the ios5 device differ than xib location